# ReactJS loading in other application returns Module parse failed ERROR in index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm using a pretty new JS dev environment ([here for details](https://github.com/superfly/fly)) and according to [this documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html) React is pretty easy to implement into other JS frameworks.

In my index.js file which is at the root of my directory, I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";




function Button() {
  return <button id="btn">Say Hello</button>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Button />,
  document.getElementById('container'),
  function() {
    $('#btn').click(function() {
      alert('Hello!');
    });
  }
);
```

and when i go to run `fly server` I get the following error:

> ERROR in ./index.js Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:9) You
>   may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. |  | function
>   Button() { |   return Say Hello; | } |

Here is my **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "fly-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "fly example app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "none"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "fly",
    "app"
  ],
```

and my webpack.config:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const bundlePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./index.js",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: { presets: ['env'] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'] },
  output: {
    publicPath: bundlePath,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname,'public'),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist"
  },
  plugins: [ new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() ]
};
```

.babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

Still fairly new to React, but I love building apps in it, but I really want to learn how to integrate it into other JS frameworks so I can use it more broadly.

Is there something I'm missing in the package.json file or the webpack.config? I have done quite a bit of looking around but haven't found much.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Do you happen to have a .babelrc?

Comment: Yes I do it is “preset”: [“env”, “react”]

Comment: If you are starting with react you could have tried Create-React-App first. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: I don't see jquery being imported, $('#btn').click(function() { , 
$ comes from jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `babel-loader` under `use.loader`. See below:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const bundlePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./index.js",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        }
        options: { presets: ['env'] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'] },
  output: {
    publicPath: bundlePath,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname,'public'),
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist"
  },
  plugins: [ new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() ]
};
```

Instead of writing the webpack configuration by yourself, I'd recommend using `create-react-app`, it is simpler. Also make sure you import jquery.

Try and let me know if this works !

Comment: Completely agree to use create-react-app but I like knowing how to build it myself, when I use create-react-app it loads just fine. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @logos_164 Do yourself a favor and read this then: https://blog.usejournal.com/creating-a-react-app-from-scratch-f3c693b84658

Comment: Thanks jay, I did read that, that’s how I had all of this configured and set up, I’m still confused on it though